# Good resource for distributed computing / scale out patterns

Tags: azure, architecture, parallel-processing, cloud, distributed-computing

we're about to start working on a parallel cloud processing application and I'm looking for good resources how to set things up. Let me set the context:

- First we load a DB with a whole lot of data
- Then we have n-instances of cloud services that will generate PDFs from the data
- PDFs will then be merged, again should be scaleable
- Result stored in DB
- Done.

I'm looking for resources to help me answer questions like:

- How can you measure progress for all of these instances? I suppose one controller instance that's monitoring. Should we use polling or a pub/sub system?
- How can you control these n-instances to start/stop/pause, whatever?
- Should the controller process be aware of the processors, or should he listen to broadcasts?
- We're thinking about a 'data'-queue, the queue from which each PDF generation instance gets the instructions to process, should we also use a 'command' queue for commands like 'start/stop'?

Or - is there already something out of the box for this? I'm looking for the 'Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture' but tailored to scaling out/parallel/cloud processing.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the -1. In case you're in doubt, I have Googled it, I have searched PluralSight and I have looked through Azure videos. I haven't ran across any patterns describing a process controller/processor setup.

Comment: have you looked the recently published Cloud Design Patterns? (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568099.aspx) the Leader Election or Pipes and Filter patterns may provide some starting point

Comment: Ahh beautiful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589778.aspx the 'Compute Resource Consolidation Pattern' seems to be almost exactly what I need - thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

As @JuneT mentioned, look at the [`Cloud Design Patterns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568099.aspx) guide. I would recommend `Leader Election` pattern as mentioned in the comment.

Some other thoughts:

- I don't think you should think about having one controller instance. All instances should have equal opportunity to become a leader. This way you're ensuring against leader failing. For deciding leader, you should look into `Lease Blob` functionality.
- You should look into `Windows Azure Diagnostics` as a way to monitor the health of these instances. `Windows Azure Diagnostics` also support custom performance counters using which you can monitor the effectiveness of each instance. For scaling, you can rely on `Windows Azure Auto Scaling` feature available in the portal or look for 3rd party solutions like `AzureWatch` from Paraleap software. The process responsible for scaling should not be a part of your solution IMHO. It should sit somewhere outside.

So the general sequence of the events could be:

1. All instances will fight among themselves to be a leader. Only one instance will be elected to be the leader. All other instances will wait out to hear from the leader (lets call them followers).
2. Leader will fetch the data from database and push the information in a queue. Followers will poll this queue. Once the messages arrive in the queue, followers will start processing those messages. Once the follower has finished one task, they will go back to the queue and see if there's more work for them. Once the leader has put all the messages in a queue, it will become a follower and work on processing the messages.
3. Once all messages have been processed, all instances will go back to step 1.

Comment: Very interesting. Of all the scenario's I had in mind, I didn't think of an approach where there was no controlling process. I'll read up on it and understand the concept. The question will be, how can we start/stop the followers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to have controller at all.  What business process starts the data load into the DB?  Whatever this process is, it can populate a queue with messages as to which PDF's need to be generated.

You then want to have a Worker Role with N number of servers that basically keep looking at the queue, pull off messages from the queue if there are any, process them (ie: generate PDFs) and remove the messages from the queue

An autoscaling solution like Azure's native basic autoscaling, or a more powerful one like [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) can create extra servers when the queue has messages in it and remove the non-needed servers when queues are depleted.

This is a very standard approach to distributing load across N number of instances.  Progress can be measured by looking at the queue and see how many messages are left in it.